# Updated data revert back to original value at MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have weird problem which is when i run update function it was successfully executed & i check at mysql database it was updated. However, after a few minutes the value at mysql database reverting to original value (before update).

As i can see my codes seems OK because i can update the value at mysql database but somehow maybe its related with $_SESSION which is i am not familiar with. Below is my code:-

```
    <?php session_start();
    $staff_no=$_SESSION['staff_no'];
    $user_name=$_SESSION['user_name'];
    $pass=$_SESSION['pass'];
    $level=$_SESSION['level'];
    include("../connect.php");
    include ("../session.php");
    $today=date('Y-m-d');

    $VendorID=$_GET['vendorid'];

    if($submit=isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
            $VendorID=isset($_POST['VendorID']) ? $_POST['VendorID'] : '';
            $CompanyName=isset($_POST['CompanyName']) ? $_POST['CompanyName'] : '';
            $Address=isset($_POST['Address']) ? $_POST['Address'] : '';
            $TelephoneNo=isset($_POST['TelephoneNo']) ? $_POST['TelephoneNo'] : '';
            $FacsimileNo=isset($_POST['FacsimileNo']) ? $_POST['FacsimileNo'] : '';
            $URL=isset($_POST['URL']) ? $_POST['URL'] : '';
            $RegisterDate=isset($_POST['RegisterDate']) ? $_POST['RegisterDate'] : '';
            $status=isset($_POST['status']) ? $_POST['status'] : '';
            $region=isset($_POST['region']) ? $_POST['region'] : '';

            $sql2 = "UPDATE vendor SET VendorID='$VendorID',CompanyName='$CompanyName',Address='$Address',TelephoneNo='$TelephoneNo',
                    FacsimileNo='$FacsimileNo',URL='$URL',RegisterDate='$RegisterDate',status='$status',region='$region'
                    WHERE VendorID='$VendorID'";

            if(@mysqli_query($con, $sql2))
            {
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
                echo "alert('Successfully edit data');\n";
                echo "</script>";
                echo "<script>window.navigate('vendordetails_add.php?vendorid=$VendorID')</script>";    
            }
            else
                echo 'the data failed to edit'.mysqli_error();

        }//if isset submit

          $sql =mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM vendor WHERE VendorID='$VendorID'");
          $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);

          $id=$row['id'];
          $VendorID=$row['VendorID'];
          $CompanyName=$row['CompanyName'];
          $Address=$row['Address'];
          $TelephoneNo=$row['TelephoneNo'];
          $FacsimileNo=$row['FacsimileNo'];
          $URL=$row['URL'];
          $RegisterDate=$row['RegisterDate'];
          $status=$row['status'];
          $region=$row['region'];         
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<form name="vendor_edit" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="VendorID" value="<?php echo $VendorID; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="status" value="<?php echo $status; ?>"  />
<table width="784" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td height="80" valign="top">    
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" background="../image/center.jpg">                              
                <tr>
                    <td height="20" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td width="81" valign="top" class="txt">Company</td>
                    <td colspan="2" valign="top"><input name="CompanyName" type="text" class="text" id="CompanyName" size="50"  value="<?php echo $CompanyName; ?>"/></td>
                </tr>      
                <tr>
                    <td height="60" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td valign="top" class="txt">Address</td>
                    <td colspan="2" valign="top"><textarea name="Address" cols="40" rows="4" class="txt" id="Address"><?php echo $Address; ?></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="21" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td valign="top" class="txt">Telephone No</td>
                    <td colspan="2" valign="top"><input name="TelephoneNo" type="text" class="text" id="TelephoneNo" size="15" value="<?php echo $TelephoneNo; ?>"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="21" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td valign="top" class="txt"> Fax No</td>
                    <td colspan="2" valign="top"><input name="FacsimileNo" type="text" class="text" id="FacsimileNo" size="15" value="<?php echo $FacsimileNo; ?>"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="21" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td valign="top" class="txt">Website</td>
                    <td colspan="2" valign="top"><input name="URL" type="text" class="text" id="URL" size="30" value="<?php echo $URL; ?>"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="21" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td valign="top" class="txt">Region</td>
                    <td colspan="2" valign="top">
                        <select name=region id="region">
                            <option value="Malaysia"<?php if ($region=='Malaysia'){ ?> selected="yes" <?php } ?> >Malaysia </option>
                            <option value="International"<?php if ($region=='International'){?> selected="yes" <?php } ?> >International</option>
                        </select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="21" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td valign="top" class="txt">Status</td>
                    <td colspan="2" valign="top">
                        <select name=status id="status">
                            <option value="Active"<?php if ($status=='Active'){ ?> selected="yes" <?php } ?> >Active </option>
                            <option value="KIV"<?php if ($status=='KIV'){?> selected="yes" <?php } ?> >KIV</option>
                            <option value="Reconsider"<?php if ($status=='Reconsider'){?> selected="yes" <?php } ?> >Reconsider</option>
                        </select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="21" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td valign="top" class="txt">Register Date</td>
                    <td colspan="2" valign="top"><input name="RegisterDate" type="text" class="text" id="RegisterDate" value="<?php echo $RegisterDate; ?>" size="15"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="21" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td colspan="2" width="613" valign="top">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="text" value="Update" />
                        <input type="button" name="back" value="Back" class="text" onClick="window.history.back(); return false;" /></td>
                </tr> 
              </td>
         </table>  
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Another page that involve $status is vendor_add.php :-

```
<?php 
session_start();
$staff_no=$_SESSION['staff_no'];
$user_name=$_SESSION['user_name'];//call session back
$pass=$_SESSION['pass'];
$level=$_SESSION['level'];
include("../connect.php");
include ("../session.php");
$today=date('Y/m/d');

if($submit=isset($_POST['submit']))
{   
    $sql=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT VendorID FROM vendor ORDER BY  VendorID DESC LIMIT 1");
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql);

    $temp=$row['VendorID'];
    $VendorID=$temp + 1;

    $today=date('Y-m-d');

    $CompanyName=isset($_POST['CompanyName']) ? $_POST['CompanyName'] : '';
    $Address=isset($_POST['Address']) ? $_POST['Address'] : '';
    $TelephoneNo=isset($_POST['TelephoneNo']) ? $_POST['TelephoneNo'] : '';
    $FacsimileNo=isset($_POST['FacsimileNo']) ? $_POST['FacsimileNo'] : '';
    $URL=isset($_POST['URL']) ? $_POST['URL'] : '';
    $RegisterDate=isset($_POST['RegisterDate']) ? $_POST['RegisterDate'] : '';
    $region=isset($_POST['region']) ? $_POST['region'] : '';

    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO vendor(VendorID,CompanyName,Address,TelephoneNo,FacsimileNo,URL,RegisterDate,region,status)VALUES
            ('$VendorID','$CompanyName','$Address','$TelephoneNo','$FacsimileNo','$URL','$RegisterDate','$region','active')";

    if(mysqli_query($con, $sql2))
        {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
            echo "alert('Successfully add data');\n";
            echo "</script>";
            echo "<script>window.navigate('vendordetails_add.php?vendorid=$VendorID')</script>";    
        }
        else
            echo 'the data could not be added'.mysqli_error();

}//if isset submit
mysqli_close($con);     
?>
```

And also my connect.php :-

```
<?php

//connection to database
//must include this file in every file to undeny data access


$dbuser        = "root";  
$dbserver    = "localhost";  
$dbpass        = "mypass123";  
$dbname        = "vendor";  


$con= new mysqli($dbserver, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ("UNABLE TO CONNECT TO DATABASE"); 
mysqli_select_db($con, $dbname) or die ("UNABLE TO SELECT DATABASE"); 

?>
```

Comment: Using the `@` error silencer is very bad practice

Comment: thanks for your advise. will remove that

Comment: Remove the `@` silencer and Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you cannot miss or ignore.

Comment: Also show us the contents of `../connect.php`

Comment: i put my connect.php above

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you use InnoDB-tables, which support transactions, each operation on one of these tables starts an implicit transaction if you do not have an explicit transaction started.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html

As long as you are within the same session (keywords "connection pooling" and "connection timeout"), your changes are visible to you, but to nobody else. When your connection finally times out, the transaction is rolled back instead of commited. This is true because you never close your session here.

To make your changes permanent, you have 3 options:

- Cast a `commit` after your operation
- Set implicit commit **and close your session properly**
- Use for example MyISAM tables (though they lack the use of foreign key constraints)

In general, you should:

- close your result sets properly (mysqli_free_result)
- make sure your connection gets closed properly whenever your script terminates
- make sure all of your transaction details are set up properly, otherwise you will run into locking issues

This should solve your problem, at the end of your whole php script part (before the `?>`), do the following:

```
mysqli_free_result($con, $sql);
mysqli_query($con, "COMMIT");
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: That's what I said? Please first __read__ and the judge. I suggest to use MyISAM to avoid troubles with transactions.

Comment: As i check on my table, the storage engine is MyISAM. Kind to elaborate to me?

The problem is  on $status. Others can update permanently but for $status it keep reverting my changes

Comment: Once his script is completed the database will be updated OR not updated. Its not like he has a `sleep(30)` in there that would explain see the chnages applied and then seeing them reverted back to the before state

Comment: The session times out because it is not closed properly. And when that happens, all transactions are reverted because not properly committed.

Comment: OP is using MYISAM therefore no transactionality exists

Comment: NOW I know that, too, but that does not mean he should not cleanup properly

Comment: And unless OP started a transaction, which I do not see them doing, then its defaulting to auto commit

Comment: Not when the session times out *rolleyes*

Comment: You have a small point about _clean up_, but all that is done automatically by PHP when the script terminates

Comment: Other fields i updated was permanent but not for $status. it will revert back to old value after a few minute

Comment: @RiggsFolly when connection pooling is activated and the session is not cleaned up properly... whatever, it's not the issue here. Maybe you update `status` anywhere else?

Comment: Now that is the most likely cause

Comment: When i register new vendor, `status` was set "Active" at insert function. Maybe that one cause the headache?

Comment: Maybe add this piece of code to your question, so we can see what happens there

Comment: any trigger set?

Comment: i tried your code as suggested. the value remain there but if i logout & login again, its change to "active" again. I notice at vendor_add.php value  `status` is "active" at insert function. maybe cause the problem?

Comment: So my suspicion is, you do something strange during the login process. Maybe another update?

Comment: under login.php i have session_unset() at top of the script. other than that the script is normal script to login

Comment: show triggers? where?

I notice as long as i didn't logout `status` still remain the updated one. After logout & login, its back to old ("Active")

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the trouble. i found the culprit of my headache. The script was developed by ex-staff. I discovered there was autorun.php script included in index.php.

autorun.php will automatically put the `status` of vendor either "Active", "KIV" & "Reconsider" based on timeframe specified in the script. Thats why everytime i update the `status` it will revert back to "Active" after a few minutes.

Anyhow thanks for ur help..!!